# public int has different value when I use it in another class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code in class A:

```
public int numberOfArrowsToWin=5;
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Wheel"))
    {
        numberOfArrowsToWin--;
    }
}
Update()
{
    Debug.Log(numberOfArrowsToWin)
}
```

I have this in class B:

```
[SerializeField]
private Text InGameArrowCounter;

private int totalArrowNumber;

private void Start()
{
    totalArrowNumber = A.numberOfArrowsToWin;
}

private void Update()
{
    Debug.Log(numberOfArrowsToWin);
    InGameArrowCounter.text = "left: " + A.numberOfArrowsToWin.ToString() + " / " + totalArrowNumber.ToString();
}
```

So the Debug.Log in class A gives me 5 4 3 2 1 0;
The debug in Class B gives me 5 4 4 4 4 4;

I can not figure out why these values are different! Please help

Comment: Is `A` referenced by class B the same instance of class A? If it's a different instance then yeah, it'll have a different value.

Comment: Do you mean `Debug.Log(A.numberOfArrowsToWin)` in `B`?

Comment: Might be helpful to show all relevant pieces of both classes. Where is `numberOfArrowsToWin` declared in class `B`?

Comment: @0xDECAFBAD `numberOfArrowsToWin` comes from `A`, which is presumably an instance of class A.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two types of memory heap and stack memory.
heap memory store static variables and methods.
And stack memory store nonstatic value and methods.

if we create an instance or object of a class in another class it creat exact same value for another class.

if you want to exact the same value you must give a reference for that variable. or make it static.

in your case, your Class A Changing the value of that public variable but your Class B Getting the same value when it accesses at the last time.

Use
Class B: MonoBehaviour
{

//code

**totalArrowNumber = (findgameobjectWichHaveClassA).GetComponent().numberOfArrowsToWin;**

//code

}

Answer (score 0):

When you used `totalArrowNumber = A.numberOfArrowsToWin;` You make your `totalArrowNumber` Equals the value of `numberOfArrowsToWin` and no the operator itself.

So when the `numberOfArrowsToWin` changed, `totalArrowNumber` won't be effected and still at the last value you give it.

#### To fix this you can:

make the totalArrowNumber = numberOfArrowsToWin; inside the update method.

it would something like this:

```
void Update()
{
    totalArrowNumber = A.numberOfArrowsToWin;
}
```